# Deep Merging Non Matching Array of Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have to arrays of objects such as:

https://plnkr.co/edit/RQs9WWs1hcxmuKGIgEhM?p=preview

I'd like to combine them such that if an array element does not appear in the second set, its brought over, if it does, the missing element is added.

So what I'd like to see is:

```
[{"car":"A","miles":100},{"car":"B","miles":100},{"car":"C","miles":100,"sold":"Y"}]

[{"car":"B","miles":100,"sold":"Y"},{"car":"C","miles":100,"sold":"Y"}]

[{"car":"A","miles":100},{"car":"B","miles":100,"sold":"Y"},{"car":"C","miles":100,"sold":"Y"}]
```

Note "Car A" only exists in first array and is carried over.

Angular's merge will only work if the objects match up. Is there an elegant way to merge two arrays of objects? I'm thinking I'll need to loop over the arrays and build up a common array. If create a unique identifier for each object make matching easier.

Comment: You just want to merge your arrays without duplicates, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to using the Lodash library (or underscore) it would make your life a lot easier (in general), it plays nice with Angular too.

You could achieve what you need by doing the following with Lodash:

```
_.values(_.extend(_.keyBy(a, 'car'), _.keyBy(b, 'car')));
```